# Django queryset of reverse manytomany relation

Tags: django

Given a FaqTopic id, I'm attempting to get a result set of respondants who have answered questions on that topic. I'm assuming this will take at minimum two queries, but I'm not entirely sure how to do it. My models look roughly like so:

```
class FaqTopic(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Respondant(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Answer(MediaReady):
    text = models.TextField( blank=True )
    respondant = models.ForeignKey( Respondant, blank=True, null=True )

class Question(MediaReady):
    text = models.CharField( max_length=255, blank=True )
    answers = models.ManyToManyField( Answer, blank=True, null=True )
    topic = models.ForeignKey( FaqTopic, blank=True, null=True )
```

I could do something like so:

```
topic = FaqTopic.objects.get(pk=topic_id)
questions = topic.question_set.all()
```

Then loop through each question and build a set of unique respondants. But that seems ugly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it in one query. This would give you a respondents who have answered a question in a specific topic.

```
respondants = Respondant.objects.filter(answer__question__topic__name = name)
```

Or if you have a `topic` object,

```
respondants = Respondant.objects.filter(answer__question__topic = topic)
```

You can read more on [lookups that span relationships here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships)